# How to install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev on Mac os

Tags: python, macos, pip, libxml2

I have installed both libxml2 and libxslt with homebrew, but it doesn't want to install libxml2-dev or libxslt-dev:
`Error: No available formula for libxml2-dev`

I have pip, port, and all I could found. I even installed the Xcode command line tools, 
but with no luck. What is the way to install libxml2-dev & libxslt-dev on Mac 10.10?

Comment: Do you have xcode command line tools installed?

Comment: @Parker yes, I do 
`xcode-select -p 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: run `xcode-select --install` to check if command line tools are installed.      `xcode-select -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` does not tell if command line tools are installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding `STATIC_DEPS`, like this

`STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml`

Comment: Great to hear :). This sometimes occurs with other libs so if you ever have a similar issue, try this again

Comment: So, `libxml2-dev` is not installed with `Homebrew` and rather with the command above?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work solve the problem for me (Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: I dont know what sorcery is that, but that's the only thing that helped after installing all dependencies and still failing to install xmlsec on Mac M1 silicon

Comment: Thanks. I was having this issue on mac, then did
      pip3 uninstall lxml
      STATIC_DEPS=true pip3 install lxml
Then I was able to get past the problem and continue with the rest of my install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installing the Command Line Tools fixed the problem for me.

I just wanted to note, that calling `xcode-select -p`
and getting the output `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
does not tell if **Xcode Command Line Tools** are installed (like stated in the comments on the question)!

For me it returned the same output but `xcode-select --install` started the installation. After the installation `xcode-select --install` printed `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

So to check if command line tools are installed better use `xcode-select --install`.