# ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which > use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, pip, ubuntu-18.04

hy,
i have a very equal problem to the problem shown here [ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe).

I'm using a jetson Nano (ubuntu 18.04).

**Error**

> Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error   ERROR: Command
> errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> /home/christopher/heartkillayolotest2/heartkillayolotest2/bin/python
> /home/christopher/heartkillayolotest2/heartkillayolotest2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py
> build_wheel /tmp/tmpwort0shc
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-g68zdlf0/opencv-python   Complete output (9 lines):
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1b_l6sbo/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py",
> line 560, in setup
> cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1b_l6sbo/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py",
> line 95, in **init**
> self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1b_l6sbo/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py",
> line 82, in get_cmake_version
> "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)   Traceback (most recent call
> last):
> Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake   ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python Failed to build
> opencv-python ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which
> use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I tried this to solve the problem but it did not help:

> (heartkillayolotest2)christopher@ccz:~/heartkillayolotest2/heartkillayolotest2$
> pip3 install --upgrade pip  Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> ./lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.2.3)

and

> (heartkillayolotest2)
> christopher@ccz:~/heartkillayolotest2/heartkillayolotest2/yolo-v3$
> pip3 install --upgrade pip Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> /home/christopher/heartkillayolotest2/heartkillayolotest2/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (20.2.3)

Unfortunatelly the error still occurs.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Jetson Nano which is a `arm64` board. There are no pre-built wheels for ARM architecture for `opencv-python`. Due to this, `pip` will attempt to build the package from sources. This will not succeed, because there is a known issue with the `cmake` dependency which is needed for the build. You can check these issues for more info:

- cmake: https://github.com/scikit-build/cmake-python-distributions/issues/115
- opencv-python: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/366

Currently, you can't build OpenCV's Python bindings via the `opencv-python` package on ARM architecture systems due to the `cmake` issue. Meanwhile you can follow the official OpenCV documentation to install OpenCV Python bindings from source: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

Note that the accepted answer is not correct. `pip` will install the build dependencies automatically (and `cython` is not needed) given that your `pip` version is greater than 19.0.

Comment: As of Feb 2021 it seems that the issue for arm64 is [https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/366#issuecomment-776462990](solved). Also, upgrading `pip` seemed to have been key for me.

Answer (score 8):

After trying most of the suggested options in this and other threads, including the most popular: trying 'pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel' before installing openCV.

What finally did the trick for me was:

```
pip install --no-use-pep517 opencv-python
```

(macOS)

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: worked for me `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot! I could install it via

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

After that I had to install opencv again. I followed the instructions of the website you gave me (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html).

I also got the same link in a python-forum (german) (https://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=49781&p=373939#p373939). Just for the case that somebody wants to read it in german.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `cmake` and `python`. Python need `skbuild` and `cython` for this job.

```
pip3 install scikit-build
pip3 install cython
```

and then

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly I was glad to early, because the error still occurs.

I did the following (perhaps these steps will help someone else).
But for me nothing solved the problem. Is there something else I can do?

**pip install cython**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3`$ pip install cython` Collecting cython   Using cached
> Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB) Installing collected
> packages: cython Successfully installed cython-0.29.21 WARNING: You
> are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the
> '/home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/bin/python -m pip install
> --upgrade pip' command.

**pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3`$ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` Collecting pip   Using cached
> pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB) Collecting setuptools   Using
> cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB) Collecting wheel
> Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB) Installing
> collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel   Attempting uninstall: pip
> Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1
> Uninstalling pip-20.1.1:
> Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1.1   Attempting uninstall: setuptools
> Found existing installation: setuptools 47.1.1
> Uninstalling setuptools-47.1.1:
> Successfully uninstalled setuptools-47.1.1   Attempting uninstall: wheel
> Found existing installation: wheel 0.34.2
> Uninstalling wheel-0.34.2:
> Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.34.2 Successfully installed pip-20.2.3 setuptools-50.3.0 wheel-0.35.1

**pip3 install scikit-build**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3`$ pip3 install scikit-build` Collecting scikit-build   Using cached
> scikit_build-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB) Collecting packaging
> Using cached packaging-20.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB) Collecting
> distro   Using cached distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.29.0 in
> /home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
> scikit-build) (0.35.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> setuptools>=28.0.0; python_version >= "3" in
> /home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
> scikit-build) (50.3.0) Requirement already satisfied: six in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from packaging->scikit-build)
> (1.14.0) Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from packaging->scikit-build) (2.2.0)
> Installing collected packages: packaging, distro, scikit-build
> Successfully installed distro-1.5.0 packaging-20.4 scikit-build-0.11.1

**pip3 install --upgrade pip**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3`$ pip3 install --upgrade pip` Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> /home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (20.2.3)

**pip3 install cmake**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3`$ pip3 install cmake` Collecting cmake   Using cached
> cmake-3.18.2.post1-py3-none-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (15.2 MB)
> Installing collected packages: cmake Successfully installed
> cmake-3.18.2.post1

**AND THIS IS THE ERROR AGAIN**

> (yolov3Tensorflow) christopher@ccz:~/TensorFlow_2_x_YOLOv3$ pip
> install opencv-python Collecting opencv-python   Using cached
> opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)   Installing build
> dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
> Preparing wheel metadata ... done Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from
> opencv-python) (1.16.1) Building wheels for collected packages:
> opencv-python   Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> /home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/bin/python
> /home/christopher/yolov3Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py
> build_wheel /tmp/tmpg3wn763c
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-spfl5_2j/opencv-python   Complete output (9 lines):
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3np44f8c/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py",
> line 560, in setup
> cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3np44f8c/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py",
> line 95, in **init**
> self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3np44f8c/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py",
> line 82, in get_cmake_version
> "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)   Traceback (most recent call
> last):
> Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake   ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python Failed to build
> opencv-python ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which
> use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I have no idea what to do know?

Comment: this is not an answer.