# Cannot install scipy on MacOS. ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, macos, scipy, pip, macos-catalina

**Note**: I checked the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe) also. But it didn't help me. And I'm somewhat new to Python and sorry if I have missed something straightforward!

Previously everything was fine with my `Makefile`. But suddenly I started to get `ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly` error. Then I realised that I get the error when I try to install `scipy` on any python project on my machine.

Command: `./venv/bin/pip install scipy`

Python version: `python3 --version` -> `Python 3.9.0`

Pip version: `pip3 --version` -> `pip 20.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

OS: MacOS 10.15.7

I was spending a couple of hours trying out everything which comes to mind but still no lock. Can someone please help?

Comment: I was not able to find a root cause for this issue, But I found a workaround for this. When I executed `which python3` I get `/usr/local/bin/python3`. `/usr/local/bin/python3 --version` gives `Python 3.9`. But `/usr/bin/python3 --version` gives `Python 3.8.2`. Then what I did was I created a symlink for `/usr/bin/python3` at `/usr/local/bin/python3` using `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3` command. Now when I executed `python3 --version` it gives me `Python 3.8.2`. And then the above issues was also fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Looking at the log of building, I see the following: `  scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/clacon2.c:175:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'ccopy_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      ccopy_(n, x, &c__1, v, &c__1);
      ^` ... so this isn't the same problem as the OP's AFAICT.