# I am building a Python project. But their is a error while installing one package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, scikit-image, python-wheel

while installing pip install ecapture some of the package installed easily but their is a error showing "ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly". Can someone explain it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe)

Comment: Hi :), please post the full error message i.e. all the text output you got on the console while installation.