# Problem deploying streamlit webapp on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

Everything works fine Locally.

However when I try pushing the project to heroku, the following error comes up.
[image]

Here is my Procfile:
`web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run application.py`

setup.sh:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"__@gmail.com\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

and requirements.txt:

```
streamlit==0.81.1
pandas==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.3.0
plotly==4.14.3
seaborn==0.11.1
numpy==1.18.5
scikit_learn==0.23.2
```

Although I'm new to this framework, I have a bit of understanding of python and a complete disaster with deploying live web app.

Any one who can point me in the right direction?

Your help is greatly anticipated and helpful.

Comment: This isn't a [tag:git] or [tag:github] issue. It's a heroku and/or pip issue, apparently; see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61365790/1256452).

Comment: Search for the combination of "pep517" with "pandas".  My guess is that, to install pandas, it is trying to compile some C code.  You can perhaps work around it by declaring the pandas requirement is a precompiled version of pandas, but I don't know how to do that.  Perhaps via the OS as a distro package?  It works locally because it was able to compile pandas on your host system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies @torek and @John Mee.

Apparently all I had to do was simple.

1. Modify `pandas == 1.2.0` to `pandas < 1.2.0` in the requirements.txt file.
2. git add, commit and push to origin and to heroku.

That's it.

Thanks again.